# I'd like to add one more LED (1->2) but don't know how to keep the same current

Tags: led

I made a simple LED circuit using a battery, a variable resistor, and a LED.
When the light intensity satisfied my demand (I do not need the full intensity) by changing the resistance, the condition was:
R1 voltage: 0.5V
LED1 voltage: 2.3V
Current: 86 uA

Now, I want to add one more LED in a series to make a dual LED system.
But I don't know how to calculate the appropriate supply voltage and resistor to keep the light intensity the same (= same current of 86 uA through 2 LEDs).
For example, what should be the resistance if I use 4.5 or 6V supply?
Any thoughts or suggestions?

LED: https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=XPEBGR-L1-0000-00E02CT-ND

[image]

Okay, now I update a new circuit to supply 5.5V using a voltage regulator.
It is battery powered (6V: 4 x 1.5V AA), so I want to keep the current (or voltage) constant ( ~ 86 uA) during the period of operation.
Do you think this circuit would work as intended?
(Let's ignore the product error between the same LEDs)

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ablic-u-s-a-inc/S-1133B55-U5T1U/1662-1276-1-ND/6601416

[image]

Or what about this design for the parallel arrangement?

I want to supply the constant voltage while the battery voltage goes down. That's why I need to use the voltage regulator.

Voltage regulator: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/LP3985IM5X-2.5-NOPB/LP3985IM5X-2.5-NOPBCT-ND/3527410

[image]

Comment: Two LEDs, even from the same batch, can have different brightnesses even when they both have exactly the same current flowing through them. Given your low level of current, I'm guessing these are being viewed by "dark-adapted" human eyes. Is that right? The reason I'm asking is because it is quite possible to get the exact same current through two LEDs, without much difficulty. But if that doesn't help you with the brightness, then it's barking up the wrong tree, so to speak.

Comment: Why not add the second LED with another resistor (!) in parallel to R1 and LED1?

Comment: Jonk: That's a good point. I just ignore the difference of two LEDs next to each other in the LED reel. I measured the power in the dark room, so you're right. The LEDs would be used in the dark environment.

Comment: Huisman: Thank you for the comment. If I connect two LEDs in a series, at least (regardless of the difference between the LEDs) I can provide the same current to the LEDs. I am not sure whether I can provide the same current for the parallel connection though it is great suggestion theoretically.

Comment: @H.Yu I don't know what you expect to do with these. If you expect LEDs ***not*** to "flicker" for example, or wander around in apparent brightness over periods of hours, then you are mistaken (or, last time I checked a decade back.) We tried to create standard candles out of them and wound up throwing away 98% of them as ***unusable*** -- that's after a 48 hour "bake-in" period operating them with a 0.05% *accurate* (NIST traceable) current source and holding them thermally stable the entire time. Not good.

Comment: @H.Yu  If all you want is "close enough," where you want them to vaguely match but don't care beyond that, then perhaps the "disappearing filament" method can be used. Get your "gold standard LED" with its current where you want it, then take each new one and set them side-by-side and adjust until they visually match. There are simple optics you can use to combine the images to make this very easy and quick. Then they will all be calibrated to each other. I suspect that can be made to work well.

Comment: According to the data sheet, Cree's PN already incorporates binning for both color and intensity. I don't expect too much part-to-part variation then.

Comment: @joribama Even binned parts flicker around. All you are promised is that they were binned. Since I used to write software and do hardware for LED binning systems used by Siemens OSRAM (in Penang, when it was owned by Siemens), I kind of know what's done and not done. Binning is great for cases where you want a batch of 7-seg displays used together in a display system to match up with each other, for example. But there's no promise of precision optical stability. That requires a bake-in and elimination of failure devices that flicker instead of becoming more stable. It's not cheap.

Comment: @jonk - I can’t argue with experience :) Thanks for sharing the lessons learned.

Comment: @jonk - Thank you so much for the comments. I know your concerns, but let's say there are no differences for the LEDs and resistors. Would the 1st and 2nd designs work appropriately under that assumption? I am not sure whether I am using the voltage regulator correctly to supply the same voltage (or current) on both LEDs

Answer (score 1):

For a supply voltage of 4.5V, what you're asking is impossible. Apparently, if you run 86uA through your LED, it has a forward voltage of 2.3V. (Forward voltage increases as the current through the LED increases.) So for two LEDs in series you'd need at least 2*2.3V=4.6V

On a side note: Applying excactly 4.6V to your two LEDs in series without a resistor is not a good idea. LEDs need a series resistor, or something else to regulate the *current* through the LED. LEDs work on constant current, not on constant voltage.

So two LEDs in series need 2*2.3V=4.6V. At 6V supply, that leaves 6V-4.6V=1.4V across the resistor.

```
U=I*R so R=U/I > R=1.4V/86uA=16.279kOhm
```

You can't get a resistor with that excact value, so get 16kOhm. That will give you a current of 1.4V/16kOhm=87.5uA

Now looking at the datasheet of your LED, you should realise that you're not even close to using the LEDs at the intended current and brightness. The LED is intended for a current somewhere around 350mA, where their light intensity is quite high. They are called X*lamp* for a reason... :-) You might get better results with an LED intended for lower current and brightness. When operated near the recommended or intended current, you will probably get more consistent light output.

Also, as others have commented already, brightness might be different for the two LEDs, even though the current is the same. Especially at these low brightness levels, a small difference in LEDs will be noticeable very quickly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhNJVd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much MartinF. Your logic helped me a lot. I updated a new circuit using a voltage regulator. Do you think it would work?

Comment: No, it will not work this way. The voltage regulator you drew is of the adjustable type. You need to set the output voltage using resistors. Look at page 20 of the datasheet.

Comment: S-1133B55 type is internally set with 5.5V output. Though I can adjust by adding resistors, I don't need to, I think

Comment: What do you think about the 2nd design then?

Comment: If you would get the S-1133B55 you're good. But that one doesn't have the ADJ pin. Because the part you drew does have the ADJ pin, I assumed you would get the adjustable version, and in that case your schematic wouldn't work. So yes, getting the fixed 5.5V version with your second schematic would work.

Comment: Your third option is not so good. You need two resistors - one in series with each (one) LED. Otherwise you'll make any differences between LEDs worse instead of better. You'll need two resistors of 2k2 (that will give you 90.9uA)

Comment: I got that. I would use S1133B55 and the output voltage is internally set at 5.5V. According to Page7 of the data sheet, it seems like Pin1 can be abandoned because it won't work for S1133B55 though it has a Pin1 because it is packaged in SOT-89-5 case. Could you please check whether the new version (Abandoned Pin1) would work well?I really appreciate in advance!

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, Martin. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Just add another resistor and LED in parallel with the existing.
If the intensities do not match then you can change the value of the resistor(s).
If you put them in series and the intensities do not match you do not have a simple fix.

It does not matter what the supply voltage is, you just need two resistors and two LEDs.  You should not need a regulator, it's a total waste.  Any voltage above 2.3 V will be sufficient.

You can try two in series with a higher supply voltage and a higher resistance, that may work fine.  Seems like additional and unnecessary work.

At this low current most of the recommendation for LED design go out the window.

At this low current it would be acceptable to power the LEDs without a resistor if you can supply the exact voltage required (e.g. 2.3V).

As far as the difference in intensity, Cree LEDs are fairly consistent and the human eye is not very good at perceiving the difference in intensity.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. But I need a voltage regulator to supply constant voltage over time because the battery voltage would go down.

Comment: @H.Yu Being battery powered you definitely do NOT want the LEDs in series.  You should try a 2.3 V regulator and connect both LEDs directly to the 2.3 V supply with no resistor.  You will only need resistors if you have to adjust the intensity where the values of the resistors would be different. The lower the output voltage of the regulator, the longer the battery will last.

Comment: Thank you. I would try that one!